# Generating a binary code with maximized Hamming distance

Tags: coding-theory

I have a (seemingly) simple question about coding theory. I feel like the answer to this should be very obvious, but I'm having some troubles with it.

I'm trying to create binary code which is $N$ bits in length and consists of $M < 2^N$ codewords, $\{m_1, m_2, ... , m_M\}$.

For a given $N$ and $M$, is there a general algorithm/approach to generate $\{m_1, m_2, ... , m_M\}$ such that the minimum Hamming distance between any two codewords in the code is maximized?

It's pretty obvious that there isn't necessarily a unique solution for a given $N$ and $M$ (if $N=4$ and $M=2$, both $\{0000, 1111\}$ and $\{0101, 1010\}$ have $d_{min} = 4$), but I'm interested to know if there's a way to generate an "ideal" code based on Hamming distance (or the full set of codes) for an arbitrary $N$ and $M$. I could imagine brute-forcing this easily enough, but it feels like there should be a simple way to express this mathematically. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In general this is an open problem. Brute-forcing is not feasible for surprisingly small values for $N$ and $d$.

Comment: This is far from obvious. BTW, most related work restricts to linear codes, which implies $M=2^k$

Answer (score 4):

The coding-theoretic function $A(n,d)$ is the maximal size of a binary code of a length $n$ with minimum distance $d$. There is no known way to find its value easily, so in other words, it is not easy to determine whether, given $n$, $M$ and $d$, an $(n,M,d)$ binary code exists. In your case, there is no easy way even to find the maximal Hamming distance, let alone construct a code with the maximal Hamming distance. Some of the known values of $A$ are tabulated e.g. [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/binary-1.html).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a python script for this O(n!), reasonable time for up to N=15

https://github.com/Golbstein/binary-code-generator/blob/master/maximum_hamming_distance_codes_generator.ipynb

Comment: Any ideas for feasible solutions with larger n? (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4288902/generation-of-max-hamming-distance-alphabet-24-10)

Comment: Is there any way we can modify your code to get the collection with distance AT LEAST 'd', particularly I was looking for d=3.