# Highest pairwise Hamming distance between k bitvectors of length n

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

What is the highest achievable pair-wise Hamming distance $d$ between all possible pairs from $k$ bitvectors each having a length of $n$ bits? The content of each bitvector can be arbitrary, only the distance has to be maximized (thus the ordering of the vectors is irrelevant).

One common application for this is in coding theory where you want to spread the code words in such a way to maximize error detection capability.

This is how far I got:

$k=2$ : 2nd vector = negated 1st vector

-> $d = n$

$k<=ld(n^2)+2$; n = power of two: (itteratively)

```
1st vector = 0....0
for i = 2 to k:
  if i is even: vector i = negated vector i-1
  if i is odd: vector where half the bits are set in packs of 2/(i+2) bits
```

e.g. $n=4$; $k=6$:   0000 1111 0011 1100  0101 1010

e.g. $n=8$; $k=8$:   00000000 11111111 00001111 11110000  00110011 11001100 010101010 10101010

-> $d = n/2$

Comment: Not very clear for me. You mean you want to find the $k$ vectors so as to maximize the _smallest_ distance?

Comment: Not exactly, my question is: what is the largest achievable distance possible if I am free to choose the vectors themselves (only the number of vectors (k) and their length (n) are given)

Comment: How does that differ from leonbloy's interpretation? Have you ever studied a book on coding theory?

Answer (score 1):

I found an question with the same intent saying this is still an open question :(

[Generating a binary code with maximized Hamming distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891528/generating-a-binary-code-with-maximized-hamming-distance?rq=1)

Nonetheless the linked tabel from the posting gives a solution for one of my cases ($n=28$, $k= 16$): $d=8$